# StringVar() Error in tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a piece of code that i have returned to and fixed so far.
It's a math game that generates a question; asks the question; checks it and adds to the score.
I am still somewhat of a beginner and have a question that i have seen many people have problems with.
Although i still can't figure it out

I have an entry widget and want to get the info out of it but continue to get errors

Can someone what's wrong, where to put v = StringVar() and why it is wrong(I'd like to learn why)

This is a game that is a WIP and so please ignore other errors. 
    import tkinter as tk
    import random as r

```
score = 0
a = 0
b = 0
answer = 0

def question_gen():
    global a
    global b
    global answer
    a = r.randint(0,100)
    b = r.randint(0,100)
    answer = (a+b)

def question_checker():
    global score
    user_input = v.get
    if user_input == answer:
        score += 1
    else:
        score += 0

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master).pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Welcome To My Wonderful Math Game\n\nHow To Play\n\nWhen you pick a difficulty a new window will pop up\nYou have to answer to the question\nBefore the timer runs out\n\nGood Luck!').pack()
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Easy', width = 25, command = self.new_window).pack()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Hard', width = 25, command = self.new_window).pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Demo2(self.newWindow)

class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master).pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = '{0} + {1} ='.format(a,b)).pack()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=v).pack()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows).pack()
    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where to put `v = StringVar()` ?

You have to store v at a place where you can reach it

1. at entry widget instanciation
2. at question checker

Possible solutions include

- declare v in upper context, thus you can access it from anywhere
- declare v as an attribute of demo2, pass it as an argument to question_checker (**sounds better to me**, Demo2 responsability is thus to show and check the answer of a question)
- declare v as an attribute of demo1, pass it as an argument to Demo2 constructor and question_checker

By the way, if you do not make use of the trace functionality (react on each variable change) of StringVar, you can get rid of StringVar

```
class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #[...]
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.pack()
        #[...]
    def close_windows(self):
        #access entry content through
        self.entry.get()
```

**Also note** that onelining widget creation an geometry in tkinter wrongly initialise your widget variables. It will always contain `None` since `pack` (and `grid`) always return None.